# Duplicate Orders when cancelling Paypal checkout

Tags: orders, paypal, duplicate

I noticed a strange activity in my magento site. I checkout using paypal then I was redirected to their gateway payment page. Then from there I decided to go back to the site by pressing the back button of the browser. I was now back in my checkout page then I decided to checkout again using paypal, I was redirected successfully to gateway payment page.

What is strange is that I get two order records in magento backend, instead of updating my previous order. Is this normal or not? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think **this is the normal workflow of Paypal Checkout**. When you validate the payment for Paypal, your order is saved so you can have an Order ID, and be sure that the items you pay for in Paypal are "blocked" (stock quantity reserved) for you in Magento.

When you go back to Magento, the cart is still here, but the order is already saved. So when you validate, it creates again another order. But don't worry, your first one is not validated and marked as paid in the backend. So you can differenciate the paypal orders that concluded and the one that didn't. Then, you can simply cancel the orders from backend and have the items automatically back in stock.